# как организовать контроль date на нескольких машинах?

Tags: linux, datetime

Есть насколько машин с линуксом, требуется организовать одновременный контроль даты и времени на них с промежутком примерно в полчаса, чем такое сделать можно? В идеальном случае, без постороннего софта на контролируемых машинах.

Comment: Что значит "контроль даты и времени"?

Comment: А что подразумевается под контролем? Необходимо знать только время (разницу во времени от исходной машины)? Или также нужно его корректировать? Укажите это в вопросе.

Comment: Про [NTP](https://www.opennet.ru/base/sys/date_and_time.txt.html) читали?

Comment: Необходимо знать время на удаленных машинах, правится в ручную к сожалению (бюрократические преграды). Про NTP читал, доступа к машине с которой синхронизируются остальные  нет.

Comment: @TheEvillurk Если у вас всё-таки есть, как вы говорите, удаленный доступ к машинам, то в чем проблема сделать сервер с `NTP`? Если ничего нельзя сделать, но доступ по `ssh` есть, напишите маленький самопальный скриптик, например. В общем, нужно знать, как можно к вашим машинам доступиться, а потом уже можно придумать костыль.

Comment: Есть несколько машин (в локальной сети, к ним доступ есть), синхронизацию по времени берут с коммутатора (к нему доступа нет). Организовать отдельный сервер с NTP нельзя по причинам не техническим :(. Требуется - получить файл\html\вывод на экран\пофиг что с выводом команды date с нескольких десятков машин одновременно раз в полчаса/час (причем именно date, потому что следить за этим будет группа людей, от компьютеров далеких вообще). В какую сторону смотреть - даже не представляю.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я проверяю время на машинах таким скриптом:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
  echo -n "$i "
  r=$(ssh $i TZ=UTC /bin/date -R)
  l=$(TZ=UTC /bin/date -R)
  if [ "$r" != "$l" ]; then
    echo "remote: $r local: $l"
  else
    echo ok
  fi
done
```

используется беспарольный *ssh*-доступ (так удобнее, чтобы пароли постоянно не вводить). пример вызова:

```
$ этот-скрипт user1@host1 user2@host2
user1@host1 remote: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 11:48:38 +0000 local: Mon, 14 Mar 2016 11:48:40 +0000
user2@host2 ok
```

видно, что на host1 часы отстают примерно на две секунды от часов на локальной машине, где запускался скрипт.

сравниваются, собственно, строки, возвращаемые командой `/bin/date -R`, т.е., если разница во времени немного меньше секунды, в большинстве случаев сравнение даст положительный результат.

---

для большей точности лучше поставить пакет с *ntpd* (обычно пакет так и называется). тогда и сверять время надо будет только в диагностических целях.
даже если у машин нет выхода в интернет, с помощью *ntpd* можно настроить синхронизацию между ними, без привязки к внешнему миру.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).